TypeError: IB.reqTickByTickData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'handler'
While debugging my python code in visual studio code I got the error message: TypeError: IB.reqTickByTickData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'handler'.
Since I am streaming via reqTickbyTickData() the data from IB TWS(and not via reqMktData), I cannot use ib.pendingTickersEvent += on_price_update to distribute the real time data to the code functions, but instead I use a "handler" directly within the
ib.reqTickByTickData(contract, "Last", numberOfTicks=0, ignoreSize=True, handler=on_tick_update).
Here is exactly how my code in this section looks like enter image description here
I checked the functions in the source code to which I am distributing the real time data via the "handler". First I distribute the data to one function and from inside this one function, I call the second function so that the data gets to the second function relying on real time data as well.
here is the first function I am calling directly from the reqTickbyTickData() via the "handler" enter image description here and from there I call the second function enter image description here. This is all. Has anyone encountered the same problem? Any hints will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

You don't get to specify a handler.  You have to use the API as it's written (or write your own).  Wherever you have subclassed EWrapper you will get the callback (ie. the handler), just override tickByTickAllLast.
You will find the proper arguments here.
https://ibkrcampus.com/campus/ibkr-api-page/twsapi-doc/#request-tick-data
So do something like
def tickByTickAllLast(self, reqId: int, tickType: int, time: int, price: float, size: Decimal, tickAtrribLast: TickAttribLast, exchange: str,specialConditions: str):
    on_tick_update() #you will have to make your own tick

